# when i import appcompat_v7 getting following errors

Tags: android

i have downloaded api 15,22. when i import v7 i am getting following error.

```
[2015-09-19 20:21:36 - AndroidHello] C:\Users\DELL\AndroidApps\WorkSpaces\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2015-09-19 20:21:36 - AndroidHello] 
[2015-09-19 20:21:36 - AndroidHello] C:\Users\DELL\AndroidApps\WorkSpaces\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2015-09-19 20:21:36 - AndroidHello] 
[2015-09-19 20:21:37 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\DELL\AndroidApps\WorkSpaces\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2015-09-19 20:21:37 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-09-19 20:21:37 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\DELL\AndroidApps\WorkSpaces\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2015-09-19 20:21:37 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-09-19 20:21:39 - AndroidHello] C:\Users\DELL\AndroidApps\WorkSpaces\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2015-09-19 20:21:39 - AndroidHello] 
[2015-09-19 20:21:39 - AndroidHello] C:\Users\DELL\AndroidApps\WorkSpaces\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2015-09-19 20:21:39 - AndroidHello]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download api 23 and in your gradle file change     compileSdkVersion to 23.

```
compileSdkVersion 23

targetSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

and make sure you import latest version of appcompat:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

and check that sdk Build-Tools 23.0.1 was installed.

[image]

Comment: I am using compileSdkVersion 23, support libraries 23.0.1, build tools 23.0.1. Build started to fail after I raised targetSdkVersion from 22 to 23. Any other ideas?

Comment: check sdk manager and check if     buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' and api 23 was installed.

Comment: wht r the things i need to download in api 23.

Comment: I updated my answer with a screenshot. you should install api 23 (SDK Platform) and Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 .